# How to fix error code -43 (copying files to my samba shares)?

Tags: macos, filesystem, error, smb

When I copy **some** files/apps to my samba shares (1 running FreeBSD and the other is running Debian Linux), I get an error code -43.

this is the text of the error message

```
operation cannot be completed as one or more required items cannot be found
```

This doesn't happen to all apps. I've encountered the problem copying calibre/ripit/textwrangler and possibly more. But I **didn't** get the error copying Chrome/VNC viewer and possibly more as well.

I've searched the net and I found an [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2039) but I don't think it applies to me.

Any ideas on how this can be avoided or perhaps a workaround? At the moment, the only workaround I can think of is to tar my files first before copying to my network shares.

thanks very much for the help :)

**update:**

I tried copying the files using the cp command and I was getting "cannot copy extended attributes" error. After removing the extended attributes via

```
xattr -rc calibre.app
```

and confirming the extended attributes are gone by running

```
xattr calibre.app
```

and I am still getting the same error. I tried copying Google Chrome which I don't have any problem with copying using drag-and-drop and I get no errors at all.

Comment: Please post your smb.conf

Comment: I had a similar situation - copying files between volumes and getting error -43 from the Finder.  But it wasn't Samba shares, it was between partitions on one hard drive.  The linked support article was very suggestive.  After I renamed the target partition to another name, then back to the original name, the problem went away.